# Why does this invariant become false?

Tags: c++, invariants

In reading accelerated c++ I was confused by the explanation given for why the invariant becomes false (see code below):

The invariant is defined by the author (in this case) as:

> The invariant for our while is that we have written r rows of output so far. When we define r, we give it an initial value of 0. At this point, we haven't written anything at all. Setting r to 0 obviously makes the invariant true, so we have met the first requirement.

```
// invariant: we have written r rows so far
int r = 0;

// setting r to 0 makes the invariant true
while (r != rows) {
    // we can assume that the invariant is true here

    // writing a row of output makes the invariant false <- WHY?
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // incrementing r makes the invariant true again
    ++r;
}   
// we can conclude that the invariant is true here
```

Then later explains...

> Writing a row of output causes the invariant to become false, because r is no longer the number of rows we have written

Given the definition i can't form a connection between the two.

Why does the invariant become false when a row of output is writing?

Comment: I might be missing something, but `endl` puts a newline, so you've now written 1 row of output and have moved onto the second. Incrementing `r` brings the number up from 0 to 1. Until you do increment `r` after the print, it holds data that you've written 0 rows, but in actuality you've written 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r` is defined to be the number of rows that have been printed.  Therefore, the invariant is true only when

```
r == number of rows that have been printed
```

Between when you print a row and when you increment `r` to update the number of rows printed so far, that invariant is not true.

`r` is equal to some number (say, `n`), and the "number of rows that have been printed" is one larger than that number (`n + 1`), because of the row you just printed.  Therefore, the invariant is not true because `n != n + 1`.

Comment: I guess what the example is trying to point out is that in a procedural language like c (and most others) you need to be aware that execution happens in steps, and thinking about each step can be important as well as thinking about the overall chunk of code. Keep in mind even in one line of code, many individual steps may be happening. Sometimes understanding a behavior depends on understanding this sort of temporal relation, a thing which is "always true" from a slightly higher point of view is actually not always true when you look at the details.

Answer (score 0):

> we have written r rows of output so far

`r` starts as 0, and at the point where the `cout` is r is still 0. The `cout` has written 1 line but `r` is 0. Therefore the invariant is temporarilly false because if you plug in the value of `r` into the statement above, it is untrue that "we have written out 0 rows of output so far".

Incrementing `r` causes the invariant to become true again.